# Findbugs throwing error BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST_OF_RETURN_VALUE even though the object is TypeSafe object

Tags: java, maven

I am facing an unusual issue with maven findbugs plugin.
It is reporting an **error** (`BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST_OF_RETURN_VALUE`) for below piece of code which I think it should not be throwing.

```
 public void call(ResourceResponse<Document> t) {

    Document resource = t.getResource(); --> this line is throwing the error.
    callback.completion(resource, null);
}
```

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: what is your findbugs configuration? is it configured to report low confidence warnings? Also what is the return type of `getResource` method? is it generic parameter `T`

Comment: yes return type of getResource is generic parameter T.I am not sure if its configured with low confidence warnings or not.But I believe even though if its configured with low confidence warnings it should not throw this error.

Comment: from what I see on the findbugs tracker, if its configured with low confidence warnings its ok to sometimes have false positive.So I belive to solve this issue we need to see your findbugs settings. also which version of findbugs are you using?

Comment: Version in use : 3.0.3.
<xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
<failOnError>true</failOnError>

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a false-positive warning, as reported here:

https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1219

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).